# Mesh position with Repulsion

Tags: javascript, three.js

Right now, my code read multiple object store into a json file. I create cube, sphere and more with different size and materials.

But I would like those mesh to have a random position around `(0,0,0)` base on a repulsion force to avoid overlaps like this :

[image]

This is generate with `position.x = Math.random() * 20 - 10;`

I would like something like this [d3.js example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/d3-repulsive). To have random position of my mesh without overlaping but all to be around the center of the scene.

I'm searching for something, but found nothing right now. I'm really new the WebGL/Three.js.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a solution that uses D3?

Comment: At all, I'm looking to reproduce the repulsion force in 3D with three.js. Like to be able to detect other objects position and be able to stabilize the model. I'm looking for a solution that using WebGL (three.js) and that it. I want to avoid the position.x = Math.random(), because I don't want overlapping. And my object need to be a bit space one between the other. So if each object have a repulse force with other, none of them touch the other and I can fix this force to have smaller or bigger space.